# Thingsboard - Charting telemetry with timestamps in the future

Tags: javascript, charts, widget, thingsboard

We need to chart some weather forecast (future) e.g. 7 day weather forecast data in TB PE. We have all the data successfully ingested as telemetry data for our asset.

We understand that the TB datepicker does not allow you to select a date range which includes dates in the future.

We found the following widget in a Github repo which could plot data with future timestamps.

https://github.com/AbCthings/thingsboard-widgets

But it forces the dashboard timeframe window to set the future time range which does work for us as we need the date range set in the widget

We had a read of this thread too:

[ThingsBoard: plot timeseries with future timestamps in a chart widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53080482/thingsboard-plot-timeseries-with-future-timestamps-in-a-chart-widget)

Has anyone had any luck making a custom charting widget which can plot telemetry with timestamps in the future using the widget's own time frame picker??

Anyone willing to share a little code to help us get started?